# How to check values before creating an object?

Tags: java

I'll try to use as an example a program that calculates the distance between two points.

Let's imagine that I have a file called Client.java (with the Client class), in which the inputs are read and where we put System.out.println to write the output(coordinates to point A and coordinates to point B), this file would look like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Cliente {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        Ponto a = new Ponto(sc.nextDouble(), sc.nextDouble());
        Ponto b = new Ponto(sc.nextDouble(), sc.nextDouble());
        System.out.println((int) Math.floor(a.dist(b)));
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

And I have another file called Point.java (with the Point class), in this file I must check before creating the object if the x or y coordinates for each point are greater than 0 and only after this check is done am I going to create the point, if any of the points are negative it must give print "iv". In other words, the code should look something like this:

```
class Ponto {
    private double x, y;
    check(x);
    check(y);
    
    public Ponto(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public double dist(Ponto p) {
        double dx = x - p.x;
        double dy = y - p.y;
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }
    
    public static void check(double x, double y) {
        if (x < 0 || y < 0) {
            System.out.println("iv");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the way I thought it would be done but this "version" gives errors and the other "versions" I managed to do the object would always be created first before the check... Can anyone explain what I'm missing?

An example of input and output for this problem could be:

```
0,0 0,0
2,0 2,0
```

Output: `2`

Another example:

```
-1.0 1.0
-1.0 1.0
```

output: `iv`

Comment: Do the check at the end of the constructor.

Comment: Your check is being called incorrectly, and even if it is called correctly, the check does nothing really. You should call it in the constructor, and throw an exception to be handled. ie IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Also `check(x)` vs `check(double x, double y)` - do you see a problem there?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Constructors always throw exceptions if they check the parameters, so no object is created. For example `new Integer("one")` will throw `NumberFormatException`. You can add a static method to check constructor parameters, or a factory method that will return `null` without an exception, but it's still something you have to check, and Java will force you to add that check if it throws a normal checked exception (why `Integer.parseInt()`, which you should use instead of `new Integer(...)`, still throws an exception).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constructor should be short and sweet.  But validating arguments is a legitimate task for a constructor.

Throw an illegal argument exception after checking in the constructor. If thrown, construction is interrupted, no object instantiated.

```
// Constructor
public Point ( final double x, final double y ) 
{
    if ( x < 0 || y < 0 ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( … ) ; }
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

If the validation is complicated, such as involving database lookups, then you should use a [*Builder*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) object to gather and validate the inputs before constructing an object of the principal class.

You may find [*Jakarta Validation*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/) helpful.